# W10 CMD forfiles

Tags: windows, cmd, forfiles

Since I had a task where I have to copy recursively files of a nested directory for work, i discovered the `forfiles`-function in windows cmd.

It worked properly and now I wonder how does the function distinguish between a file and a directory?

If every file had a file extension like .jpg .png .xls or something like that, I could understand it, but some of my files came without extensions, but it still did its job.

As I'm used to linux, I tried to google the sourcecode, but windows applications aren't opensource, so if anybody can explain me, how does it work, it would be very interesting to know.

PS: why does this got downvoted? its a general question

Comment: Short answer: The same way, windows explorer knows how distinguish between files and directories. Long answer [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

Comment: Use [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)'s `@isdir` variable which holds either `TRUE` or `FALSE`: `forfiles /P "…" /M "…" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE (echo The currently iterated item @path is a directory.) else (echo The currently iterated item @path is a file.)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command will eventually call the Windows `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile` functions. Those return a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure which may contain a `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag. If that flag is not set, it's a file.

Answer (score 1):

Internally there is quite a difference between a file and a directory, and it's no surprise that typical file/directory handling commands know about this. The fact that a file doesn't have an extension (or that a directory is called "directory.jpeg") does not cause any confusion within those commands.

If you check `forfiles`' "man page" (`forfiles /?`), you might see that the `/C` switch gives you access to the `@isdir` variable, which can tell you the difference: are you dealing with a directory (value:`TRUE`) or a file (value:`FALSE`)?